# ReactJS - onhashchange vs addEventListener("hashchange")

Tags: reactjs, addeventlistener, hashchange

I'm using a hashchange listener in my React component. The listener is mounted in componentDidMount() via `onhashchange` rather than using `addEventListener()` through the commented line. **Is there a difference between the two?**

```
componentDidMount:function(){
    onhashchange=this.checkHash
    //window.addEventListener("hashchange", this.checkHash);
},
```

It's calling a custom function checkHash().

**How do I unmount the listener?**

Is it the same as:

```
componentWillUnmount:function(){        
    window.removeEventListener("hashchange", this.checkHash);
}
```

Thanks.